# Not getting full path when using os.path.abspath in conjunction with os.listdir

Tags: python, parsing, directory, os.path

I am trying to use the following line of code to get all the pathnames of files in a given directory:

```
trainDB = [os.path.abspath(x) for x in os.listdir("C:/Users/sean/Documents/uni/ANLP/Data/Train/DrugBank")]
```

But the ouput is like so:

```
['C:\\Users\\sean\\Documents\\uni\\ANLP\\Data\\19-norandrostenedione_ddi.xml', ...]
```

Whereas I want/expect the resultant path to be:

```
`'C:\\Users\\sean\\Documents\\uni\\ANLP\\Data\\Train\\DrugBank\\19-norandrostenedione_ddi.xml'
```

I dont understand why the Train/DrugBank diretories are not in the path, if its any use I am runnig these commands from the `ANLP` directory which is one above `Data`

Comment: `listdir` only returns the contents of the given directory. You need to `join` that to the given directory, then perhaps pass it to `abspath`.

Comment: `abspath` is joining the current working directory with the filename from `listdir`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet solved my problem following the advice of @Peter Wood.

```
pathtrainDB = 'C:\\Users\\sean\\Documents\\uni\\ANLP\\Data\\Train\\DrugBank'
filestrainDB = os.listdir(pathtrainDB)
filepathstrainDB = [os.path.join(pathtrainDB,f) for f in filestrainDB]
```